# Batch - B) is unexpected at this time

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

Trying to edit a registry querying batch file to set the path from the registry's entry.
I'm being returned with this error when attempting to run the batch file.

If I input a snippet manually in to command prompt it will read and set the path perfectly.

> B) was unexpected at this time
>
> @For /F "Tokens=2* skip=2" B)

```
SETLOCAL ENABLEEXTENSIONS

:v64bita2
@For /F "Tokens=2* skip=2" %A In ('REG QUERY "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Bohemia Interactive Studio\ArmA 2" /v "MAIN"') Do (set ARMA2PATH=%B)
IF NOT DEFINED ARMA2PATH (GOTO v32bita2) ELSE (GOTO v64a2oa)

:v32bita2
@For /F "Tokens=2* skip=2" %C In ('REG QUERY "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Bohemia Interactive Studio\ArmA 2" /v "MAIN"') Do (set ARMA2PATH=%D)
IF NOT DEFINED ARMA2PATH (GOTO uaca2) ELSE (GOTO v64a2oa)

:uaca2
@FOR /F "tokens=2* delims=   " %I IN ('REG QUERY "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Bohemia Interactive Studio\ArmA 2" /v "MAIN"') DO (SET ARMA2PATH=%J)
IF NOT DEFINED ARMA2PATH (GOTO stda2) ELSE (GOTO v64a2oa)

:stda2
@FOR /F "tokens=2* delims=   " %K IN ('REG QUERY "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Bohemia Interactive Studio\ArmA 2" /v "MAIN"') DO (SET ARMA2PATH=%L)
IF NOT DEFINED ARMA2PATH (GOTO ENDfailA2) ELSE (GOTO v64a2oa)

:v64a2oa
For /F "Tokens=2* skip=2" %E In ('REG QUERY "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Bohemia Interactive Studio\ArmA 2 OA" /v "MAIN"') Do (set ARMA2OAPATH=%F)
IF NOT DEFINED ARMA2OAPATH (GOTO v32a2oa) ELSE (GOTO RUN)

:v32a2oa
For /F "Tokens=2* skip=2" %G In ('REG QUERY "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Bohemia Interactive Studio\ArmA 2 OA" /v "MAIN"') Do set (ARMA2OAPATH=%H)
IF NOT DEFINED ARMA2OAPATH (GOTO uaca2oa) ELSE (GOTO RUN)

:uaca2oa
@FOR /F "tokens=2* delims=   " %M IN ('REG QUERY "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Bohemia Interactive Studio\ArmA 2 OA" /v "MAIN"') DO (SET ARMA2OAPATH=%N)
IF NOT DEFINED ARMA2OAPATH (GOTO stda2oa) ELSE (GOTO RUN)

:stda2oa
@FOR /F "tokens=2* delims=   " %O IN ('REG QUERY "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Bohemia Interactive Studio\ArmA 2 OA" /v "MAIN"') DO (SET ARMA2OAPATH=%P)
IF NOT DEFINED ARMA2OAPATH (GOTO ENDfailA2OA) ELSE (GOTO RUN)

ENDLOCAL

:run

title CMG - Mod Downloader

echo .
echo Downloading Mods Now
echo .

:ENDfailA2
echo ArmA 2 Not Installed
pause

:ENDfailA2OA
echo ArmA 2 OA Not Installed
pause
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in batchfiles you will have to double your `%`.
for example your first line:

```
@For /F "Tokens=2* skip=2" %%A In ('REG QUERY "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Bohemia Interactive Studio\ArmA 2" /v "MAIN"') Do (set ARMA2PATH=%%B)
```

Also, you could set the first line to

```
@echo off
```

then you don't have to put an `@` to each line

Comment: Ah, a simple over-look. 

Thank you for the help (memory-refresh) :)